# SQL String parsing and fetching certain value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string  which i have to parse and retrieve the bill id fields. My string can have either one bill id or multiple bill id's.

```
Declare @str nvarchar(1000)

set @Str = 'Process of submitting the bill id: AS12345 is send back to Customer. Bill id:WE23456 and Bill id: AS12345 came from customers'

Declare @t table (billid varchar(100))
Insert into @t values ('AS12345'),('WE23456'),('AS12345')

select distinct billid from @t
```

Comment: what do you want to do with this?

Comment: I have to pick the bill id's from a string.

Comment: i dont even saw any problem with your code.. its working fine and return the billid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a Parser Function.

```
Declare @str nvarchar(1000)
set @Str = 'Process of submitting the bill id: AS12345 is send back to Customer. Bill id:WE23456 and Bill id: AS12345 came from customers'

-- Clean and Normalize String
Set @Str = Replace(Replace(Replace(@Str,'Bill id','BILLID'),'BILLID :','BILLID:'),'BILLID: ','BILLID:')
Select Distinct BillID=Replace(Key_Value,'BILLID:','') 
 From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Str,' ') 
 Where Key_Value Like 'BILLID%'
```

Returns

```
BillID
AS12345
WE23456
```

The UDF

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('hello world. It. is. . raining.today','.')

    Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
    As
    Begin
       Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
       Insert Into @ReturnTable Select Key_Value = ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
       Return 
    End
```

Comment: Thank you John, I thought system functions such as Stuff can do parsing

Comment: @goofyui I'll noodle it a bit more, Perhaps there is a more elegant way

Comment: @goofyui Full-Disclosure.  Your process revealed a bug in my oringnal parser.  When two consecutive IDENTICAL strings , only one would be returned.  Since you only wanted distinct, it wouldn't matter for this test, HOWEVER, the parser should be correct as a foundation helper.   The UPDATED function listed above has the SAME FUNCTIONALITY and should be updated on your system.

Comment: @goofyui I should also add, it is faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom function using the regular expression `id:\s*[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]+`.

Comment: keyword to filter the statement is bill id: